# flask sqlalchemy getting Unknown column error despite having them

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

So... I'm trying to commit some sql from flask app inside, and the model code is as follows:

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = '_users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_email = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(50), nullable=False, unique=True)
    user_reg_date = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=False)
    last_login = db.Column(db.TIMESTAMP, nullable=True)
    passwd = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(80), nullable=True)
    social_id = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(80), nullable=True, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, user_email, passwd, social_id):
        self.user_email = user_email
        self.user_reg_date = current_time()
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.social_id = social_id


class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = '_players'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    player_unique_id = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('_users.id'))
    affiliated_crew_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('crew.id'))
    player_nick = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(50), unique=True)
    player_highscore = db.Column(db.Integer)
    player_badge = db.Column(db.VARCHAR(100))
    player_rank = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, player_unique_id, user_id, affiliated_crew_id
                 , player_nick):
        self.player_unique_id = player_unique_id
        self.user_id = user_id
        self.affiliated_crew_id = affiliated_crew_id
        self.player_nick = player_nick
        self.player_highscore = 0
        self.player_badge = None
        self.player_rank = 0
```

I already have the proper columns in the SQL(as I written these from pre-made tables) it's all correct.

the part committing the sql is as follows:

```
player = Player(player_unique_id=00000, user_id=user_num, affiliated_crew_id=crew_id
                , player_nick=nick)
db.session.add(player)
db.session.commit()
```

and it's returning this:

> sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, "Unknown column '_users.id' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO _players (player_unique_id, user_id, affiliated_crew_id, player_nick, player_highscore, player_badge, player_rank) VALUES (%(player_unique_id)s, _users.id, %(affiliated_crew_id)s, %(player_nick)s, %(player_highscore)s, %(player_badge)s, %(player_rank)s)'] [parameters: {'player_unique_id': 84658, 'affiliated_crew_id': '1', 'player_nick': 'player', 'player_highscore': 0, 'player_badge': None, 'player_rank': 0}]

what am I doing wrong here? searching didn't help so far...

Comment: What if you try add Id in your _users __init__ function  self.id=id

Answer (score 1):

I was using raw `User` class to get the `User.id`, which kept returning None.

since `User` was my `flask-login`'s user class I had to bring my user id by using `current_user.id`.

so fixing my `user_num` init, which had `user_num = User.id` to `user_num = current_user.id` fixed everything...

thank you everyone who looked into the problem...